# Keep receiving error on SELECT SUM Query

Tags: mysql, select, sum

Okay, so I found the mysqli format:

```
$resultDN7 = $db->query("SELECT SUM(`donation_resources`) as `totalDN7` FROM ztn_com_donations WHERE donation_playerid='$player_id' AND donation_corpsid='$player_corpsid' ");
$rowDN7 = $resultDN7->fetch_assoc();
echo $rowDN7['totalDN7'];

$pladon = ( $rowDN7['totalDN7'] );
```

Okay if you notice that last line, I must get the result changed into a variable. I could not find documentation on that, just an example as below:

```
if ($rowDN7)
{ $pladon = $row[0]; }
```

Is this correct?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, don't you think? The second argument to [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/mysql_result) should be a number but you are passing it the string *donation_resources*

Comment: I did try the Sum(...) AS .... but that failed as well.

Comment: Well shit. Tired coding is sloppy coding. The 'ORDER BY ### DESC LIMIT 1' did not need to be there. The intent is to sum all rows matching the criteria...Apologies gents. I corrected my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_result()` expects parameter 2 to be `int` and you are giving it `string`

The documentation says

> The row number from the result that's being retrieved. Row numbers start at 0.

Since in your case `DISTINCT SUM(donation_resources)` it will only return 1 row

It should be like

```
echo mysql_result($resultDN7, 0);
```

Where `$resultDN7` is the resource and `0` is the row

Comment: I saw that format somewhere zzlalani, and had yet to try it; Thank you. @ everyone - the query in question did work about 5 years ago with no issues. Is there a deprecation problem or possibly a different version of mysql?

Comment: In all programming languages and Databases, PHP and MySQL are the most highly unpredictable language and tool.

Comment: The best practice is to always look for documentation when your functions dont work

Comment: Yes I completely follow that process - I've searched far and wide for the right documentation; however PHP.net is all about mysqli now and as I said I'm not upgrading the code until everything is finished.

Comment: @Aesirnaut It would be much easier to update it **before** it's finished

Comment: I'm grumpily trolling php.net as you type. *facepalms  - lol thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: And btw @Phil is right, you must rather upgrade to `mysqli_*`